# fit final model on both train and test data

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret

I used cross validation to find optimal hyperparameters using the Caret package in R. This model is fit on the complete training data, but I want to train the final model on both the train and test data. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the best parameter and fit it in as a single grid:

```
library(caret)
idx = sample(nrow(iris),100)
dat = iris
dat$Species = ifelse(atd$Species=="versicolor","v","o")
traindf = dat[idx,]
testdf = dat[idx,]

mdl = train(Species ~ .,data=traindf,method="gbm",
trControl=trainControl(method="cv"))

train_fit = train(Species ~ .,data=traindf,method="gbm",
                  trControl=trainControl(method="cv"),
                  tuneGrid = mdl$bestTune)

test_fit = train(Species ~ .,data=testdf,method="gbm",
                  trControl=trainControl(method="cv"),
                  tuneGrid = mdl$bestTune)
```

Since you did not provide the data or more information. this is the straightforward way. Otherwise you would call the method, for example in this case `gbm()` and fit again.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I see you specify method = "cv" in trainControl, which I feel does not make sense if we just want to fit a final model without tuning parameters. Are there reasons to use method= "cv" when we just want to fit a model with best tuning parameters, or does it indeed make more sense to just use method= "none"?

Comment: yes you can use method="none". thanks for pointing that out